# How to sort data based on the text shown in the frontend that is stored as UUID?

Tags: java, spring, sorting, uuid

We have an Angular application with a Spring Boot back-end and a PostgreSQL database. We have a couple of statuses that are stored as UUIDs in the database, but in the front-end we transform them into English words. In a table I want to be able to sort them based on the English words rather than the UUIDs. The sorting has to happen in the back-end. I don't want to create another column in the database just for this. Any suggestions on the approach?

Right now when I click sort on the front-end, the back-end sorts based on the UUID which doesn't match the correct order of the statuses.

I thought of modifying the UUIDs, but that looks fishy, and introduces a lot of complications later.

Comment: Either you need to move this type of sorting to the front-end, or the back-end needs to be aware of the names of the statuses to be able to sort on them.

Comment: You are trying to embed meaningful messages within UUID values? That is really not the purpose of a [UUID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: We ended up adding a new column to the table with the labels used by the frontend. Thank you for the responses.